# TFS Build - Sending MSBuild Proj Values into the vstest runtime

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

We have unit tests that are built and run during our [TFS Build process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms253138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  It is a very large project with a complex build time.  There are parameters used in the msbuild .proj files that get passed down to child projects, etc.

Sometimes the unit test runtime needs some of these .proj parameters (which can only be known at build time) in order to function correctly.

My predecessor managed this by creating a file at build time using post-build events (e.g. ECHO SomethingINeedToKnow=True >> somefile ) in the unit test project's vcxproj file.

Then at runtime the unit test dll's on AssemblyInitialize event looks for this file and parses the needed values, injecting them into the test runtime.  It's really quite ingenious.

However, the senior architects do not like hacks and they want everything to be done the Microsoft way, if at all possible.

**So my question is this:** i*s there a native, Microsoft-sanctioned way to pass values inherited by the vcxproj at build time into the unit test runtime?*

I think the answer is no, and that the current solution is the best solution, but I want to make sure.

p.s. The code under test is typically unmanaged C++ and the unit test projects are managed C++ `using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting` (10.0 I believe)

Comment: I don't think this is specific to test it is really a question about how to pass parameters to any external process as the unit tests are probably executed by mstest.exe.  Unfortunately it does not look like the vanilla exec task has a way to set environment variables for the process you are launching.  In the end generating a batch file might be the best way.

Answer (score 1):

I know supplying [Run Time Parameters to Tests](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/09/04/supplying-run-time-parameters-to-tests/) can be achieved through VNEXT build. Not sure how to send proj values into the vstest runtime.